# html5 canvas increase image size

Tags: html5-canvas

I am looking for a solution to show smaller image in bigger canvas. would like to know if there is a method to increase image size 100% without distorting it in html5 canvas runtime on safari and chrome browsers .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

If the image is vector based it would double size with little noticeable distortion.

If the small image is high resolution (eg 300 dpi instead of the webs traditional 72dpi) you can double the size with little noticeable distortion.

Otherwise...

Try just putting the image in an image element and having the browser double the size.  Modern browsers use Bicubic interpolation and do a reasonable job of scaling.

Take the image into Photoshop and enlarge it there.  Try both Bicubic Smoother and Bicubic Sharper to see which works best for your particular image.

If none of these are workable for you, try "cheating" by just scaling X 2 and then apply a slight blur to hide the distortion.  A useful Gausian/Box blur library is Quasimondo's stackblur: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html